# How to insert 2 objects at the same time but with a difference of 1 second?

Tags: elixir, ecto

There're situations when I need to insert 2 objects of the same Struct into a database, via Ecto, such that `inserted_at` or `updated_at` of **one of the Struct** should differ only by 1 second from the other one.

I insert 2 struct objects sequentally, one after right the other, and their `inserted_at` and `updated_at` turn out to be identical. Whereas I want a 2nd object to have `inserted_at` and `updated_at` greater by 1 second to a 1st one, so that later on when I retrieve them from a database and show on a page, data will make more sense.

Supplying `inserted_at` or `updated_at` + 1 second to a `changeset` structure of a 2nd object  didn't help because they got ignored by Ecto, and both objects got identical `inserted_at` and `updated_at` values.

Calling `:os.sleep(1000)` between the calls to `insert` will be a bad option.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One might use [`Ecto.Repo.insert_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3) for this exact purpose. According to docs:

> If the schema contains an autogenerated ID field, it will be handled either at the adapter or the storage layer. **However any other autogenerated value, like timestamps, won't be autogenerated** when using `insert_all/3`.

That said, one should explicitly set `inserted_at` and `updated_at` values for both changesets using `DateTime.utc_now/0` and then call `update_all/3`.

*Beware!* If your records have other calculated by *Ecto* fields, all of them should be also set explicitly.

---

Another option would be to insert both and then alter the second one, but this is definitely worse since it requires 3 queries instead of one in the approach above.